# why zbar and zxing could not decode this barcode?

Tags: qr-code, barcode, zxing, zbar

here is the image:

[image: View barcode]

I have tried zbar, pyzbar, zxing, and could not decode it successful.
Did anyone could decode this barcode?

Answer (score 1):

The barcode image is totally non-compliant with the UPC/EAN symbol standards.  All of the bar and space widths must be multiples of 1x, 2x, 3x, and 4x.  If you look at the image's bars and spaces, they are all over the place.

Compare to the the following:

[image: EAN 6933171156891]

Comment: Thank you for your reply，I have tried yours, the zbar algorithm can decode it successfully. Did there have any else method that I can decode my image, or translate to your version to decode it ?

Comment: Need to know more about how you are displaying the barcodes.  Is this in a browser?  Or native code?  What is the end use for these barcodes?